# How to have a loading screen while data is being loaded on android?

Tags: android, loading

I am trying to understand how to load a screen while all my methods and data is completely done loading. I noticed apps like Gmail, instagram, etc. have a little loading icon in the middle over white while the screen fully loads, and some of my data takes a while to load so I was wondering how I can have the screen in the meanwhile show a loading screen instead of flashing the data noticeably when it is ready.

One thought I had was surrounding the whole view in a relative layout and on load keep the layout within the relative layout visible and then switching to the other view... I do not know if that is the smartest way but let me know if there is another more efficient method. I will need this to be used for every screen as it makes a call to the servers - pre-cache, also some screens do not cache the data since it makes no sense.

Let me know if there are any easy libs or a modular technique I can implement outside of my xml layout plan.

Comment: Firstly, that is not screen. If you are working with AsyncTask then you can use Progress Dialog to show progress or loading view. Check this doc - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html

Comment: Full tutorial is here. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_progressbar.htm

Comment: I am using Retrofit to grab the data, which does work Async, is there a progress dialog provided or an easy way to implement it with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your dialog

```
ProgressDialog progress;
```

When you're ready to start the progress dialog:

```
progress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "dialog title",
"dialog message", true);
```

and to make it go away when you're done:

```
progress.dismiss();
```

Comment: Thanks is there a way to mask the whole screen, change the dialog box to overlay everything? - or to set a custom view for it?

Comment: if this answer provides your solution, please accept it as solution

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty much it is. you can have different activity for loading with different layout with progress bar or same activity with progress bar.

if you downloading large amount of data but you dont want user to wait you  can download all the data  n save it on device. next time if user open the app you show them data from saved data and then update it on both side in background.